# How to Revive Wired Internet and Setup Wireless?

Tags: wireless, drivers, internet, dell, broadcom

I'm trying to salvage a laptop long-abandoned by its owner and, just recently, given to me. Things were so messed-up that I just had to wipe the slate clean by replacing everything with Ubuntu 13.04.

In its post-installation state, it couldn't use wireless Internet, only wired. I checked the "Software and Updates" window's "Additional Drivers" tab to find this:

```
- Broadcom Corporation: BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller
This device is not working.
    (-) Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary)
    ( ) Do not use the device
- Unknown: Unknown
This device is not working.
    ( ) Using Non-free firmware for Linux kernel drivers from linux-firmware-nonfree (proprietary)
    ( ) Continue using a manually installed driver
    (-) Do not use the device
```

As can be seen, I had the Broadcom driver installed.

The problem is that the installation has frozen at  80%. I'm thinking that the installation might need some information online to continue, but the laptop has lost its ability to sense the wired Internet it is already connected to. How can I make it re-sense the wired Internet?

Here is the current data on the laptop's state:

**Ifconfig**

```
lo  Link encap:Local Loopback
    inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0   
    inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
    UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
    RX packets:3291 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:3291 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0  
    RX bytes:267301 (267.3 KB)  TX bytes:267301 (267.3 KB)
```

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
  *-network:0 UNCLAIMED
description: Ethernet controller   
product: BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX
vendor: Broadcom Corporation   
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
version: 02   
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm cap_list   
configuration: latency=64
resources: memory:dfdfc000-dfdfdfff
  *-network:1
description: Network controller
product: BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller
vendor: Broadcom Corporation
physical id: 3
bus info: pci@0000:03:03.0
version: 02
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: bus_master
configuration: driver=wl latency=64
resources: irq:17 memory:dfdfe000-dfdfffff
```

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/PM/GMS/910GML Express Processor to DRAM Controller (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #4 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev d3)
00:1e.2 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1e.3 Modem: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) AC'97 Modem Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FBM (ICH6M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 03)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801FBM (ICH6M) SATA Controller (rev 03)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX (rev 02)   03:01.0 CardBus bridge: Ricoh Co Ltd RL5c476 II (rev b3)
03:01.1 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C552 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 08)
03:01.2 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 17)
03:03.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller (rev 02)
```

As to the second device, I am not sure what it is, but the "Continue using..." seems to imply that the driver is already there ready to be used, so I am thinking of choosing the second option after the first problem is resolved. Would you guys agree?

Comment: Please post what `lshw -C network` and `lspci -nn` tells you.

Comment: For the wired card: run `modprobe b44` and check with `ifconfig`, and I need you to show me the output of `lspci -nn`, not just `lspci`.

Answer (score 2):

Installation of the Broadcom STA wireless driver adds a blacklist for the module ssb which is also used by the driver b44 used by your ethernet card. If you load the driver b44:

```
sudo modprobe b44
```

I suspect your ethernet will come to life. If, after you do this, your wireless is still working as expected, undo the ssb blacklist:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
```

Comment out the ssb line:

```
#blacklist ssb
```

Proofread, save and close gedit. You should be all set.